Implementing Azure B2C single sign on shared between multiple apps
I want to implement SSO accross multiple apps. My requirement is that we will login in one app and switch between different apps withoout having to login again.
App 1- React Spa
App 2 - .Net based.
I am using Azure msal react library in App1 and it works perfectly. I am able to redirect to SSO login page and it returns to my redirect_uri with id_token. The library takes care of everything and it is super easy to use. It stores id_token, refresh_token in my session storage.
Now I want to navigate to App 2. What is the best way to silently login the user in App 2 without redirecting user to SSO login page again ?
Also, once the user will redirect from App2 to App 1 again how can I silently login user without redirection. I used ssoSilent but it seems to be having limitation with third party cookie in most browsers. Is there a way i can login user using refresh token in msal library ?
Thanks,
Rashmi
App 2 - I am thinking of calling the outh token api using the refresh token and get the claims. Wanted to know if that will be the right approach or not.
App 1 - I don't find any way other than using ssoSilent but it has limitation. I can call the oAuth token api in this case also but not sure how can I store all the details (id_token/access_token/refresh_token) in the same way msal library stores.

please make sure to read [ask] page

This is not an answer, just a question for clarification (improve your original question if relevant):
So you use MSAL in App1, and it is configured to connect to your B2C directory (as you said, you have configured a redirect URL, and it works). Do you also use MSAL for App2, or some other (more Microsoft-agnostic OAuth library)?
The 2nd thing is, as you wrote, App1 stores credentials in the session storage, i.e. in the user's browser, locally. If App2 is a server-side application, it won't have direct access to these credentials. If you want to write a shared frontend-backend application (with React in the Browser and .Net on the backend server), you will need to synchronize/share credentials between both, somehow.
(I believe according to the original RFC6749, the browser (and its storage) was considered unsecure/potentially compromised, so OAuth was designed to never hand important secrets (especially the long-living refresh token) to the browser directly; (MSAL does not care and compromises security  in favor of comfort). In my implementations, I usually let the frontend app (your App1?) delegate the login to the backend app (your App2?), and only hand a proxy token (not any of the Oauth tokens) to the frontend; for any API requests, the frontend then has to proxy through the backend, which swaps the token.) (But instead of making your App2 an OAuth gateway, which is a considerable programming effort, maybe there are OAuth gateways for that purpose and you can use one of those)
